# Adding index in between two datetime indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

Dataframe: I have a datetime index, but it is missing the 17:00 each day. How would I add additional `yyyy-mm-dd 17:00` row to every day?

Say if I have:

```
                price
2017-01-01 16:55  1.2
2017-01-01 17:05  2.3
2017-01-01 17:10  3.4
.
.
.
2019-01-01 16:55  23
2019-01-01 17:05  29
2019-01-01 17:10  20
```

I want to add rows at 17:00 with `NaNs` so that I have

```
2017-01-01 16:55  1.2
2017-01-01 17:00  NaN
2017-01-01 17:05  2.3
2017-01-01 17:10  3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reindex`:

```
from io import StringIO
# sample data
s = """date_time,price
2017-01-01 16:55,1.2
2017-01-01 17:05,2.3
2017-01-01 17:10,3.4"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])
df = df.set_index('date_time')

# create a date range with the index min and max and set to whatever freq you would like
new_idx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='5T')
df.reindex(new_idx)

                    price
2017-01-01 16:55:00   1.2
2017-01-01 17:00:00   NaN
2017-01-01 17:05:00   2.3
2017-01-01 17:10:00   3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different `date` , you will need `groupby` here, and I am using `resample`

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x : x.resample('5 min').mean()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
Out[13]: 
                     price
date_time                 
2017-01-01 16:55:00    1.2
2017-01-01 17:00:00    NaN
2017-01-01 17:05:00    2.3
2017-01-01 17:10:00    3.4
```